# Are there best practices for implementing an asynchronous game engine loop?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, game-loop

I have implemented a game engine loop as follows:

```
public static Boolean Start ( )
{
    if (hasBoard)
    {
        //  start engine on worker thread
        asyncTask = new AsyncResult ( stopEngine, asyncTask );
        isRunning = ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem ( startEngine, asyncTask );

        if (isRunning)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ( "[{0}] Engine started",
                DateTime.Now.ToString ( "hh:mm:ss" ) );
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine ( "[{0}] Engine failed to start",
                DateTime.Now.ToString ( "hh:mm:ss" ) );
        }
    }

    return isRunning;
}

public static void Stop ( )
{
    Console.WriteLine ( "[{0}] Engine stopping",
        DateTime.Now.ToString ( "hh:mm:ss" ) );

    asyncTask.SetAsCompleted ( null, false );
}

private static void startEngine ( Object task )
{
    while (!( (IAsyncResult)task ).IsCompleted)
    {
        Thread.Sleep ( 10000 );

        Console.WriteLine ( "[{0}] Engine running",
            DateTime.Now.ToString ( "hh:mm:ss" ) );
    }
}

private static void stopEngine ( IAsyncResult iaResult )
{
    //  clean up resources

    Console.WriteLine ( "[{0}] Engine stopped", 
        DateTime.Now.ToString ( "hh:mm:ss" ) );

    isRunning = false;
}
```

I am using the `AsyncResult` class recommended by Jeff Richter in his article, [Implementing the CLR Asynchronous Programming Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163467.aspx). In order to be able to stop the engine from the UI, the implementation I used was a bit off from the standard asynchronous pattern. This implementation works as expected, but when I divert from a standard practice, I revert to the SO community to ensure I am doing things the right way.

Are there any issues with this implementation that anyone can see?

Comment: in a game engine loop, wouldn't you simply spawn a new thread rather than using a pool thread?

Comment: @Mitch: I'm not really sure. I believe that spawning a new thread is standard. I don't know that there is anything wrong with using a Threadpool thread. This game engine is super lightweight. Also, since a WinForms UI is *in control*, I thought this would be a good way to work the game loop.

Comment: Why are you using *any* threads in a game loop? If you *need* any (which should really be questioned well), the threads should likely be pre-spawned threads for a *specific well-defined purpose* (e.g. always 2 threads, etc. that live continuously) that work off a queue or other synchronization. However, best is likely just to keep it "KISS".

Comment: @pst: probably because this is my first attempt at building and understanding a very simple game engine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since this sounds like a project you have control over, I would suggest you ditch APM and use the `Task`-based model provided in .NET4.  This is the recommended approach for .NET4 instead of APM.  The `Task` class is part of the **Task Parallel Library** ([TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx)) but it's great for these basic asynchronous jobs as well.

```
private CancellationTokenSource cts;

public void StartEngine()
{
    if (cts == null)
    {
        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GameLoop(cts.Token), cts.Token);
    }
}

private void GameLoop(CancellationToken token)
{
    while (true)
    {
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Debug.WriteLine("working...");
    }
}

public void StopEngine()
{
    if (cts != null)
    {
        cts.Cancel();
        cts = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Agreed, but I would add a LongRunning option when creating the task.

Comment: I made the modification to add the LongRunning option: `Task.Factory.StartNew ( ( ) => startEngine ( cancelSource.Token ), cancelSource.Token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default );`

Answer (score 2):

I would say that It's implied that tasks are short-lived when using the thread pool since the number of threads in it is limited.

In you case I would use a BackgroundWorker instead since you mentioned winforms. BW handles synchronization for you and are therefore able to update the GUI without using InvokeRequired etc.

Comment: *It's implied that tasks are short-lived when using the thread pool* - not according to Jeff Richter...unless I really missed something. However, I do see your point in keeping threadpool thread-tasks short.

Comment: @IAbstract: Do you have a reference for that? Would be interesting to read.

Comment: I would have to find it again - it's been well over a year and a half since I made the comment. The implication that a task is short lived could be due to the default treatment - i.e., we have to set a task as long running if we expect long execution time. There must  have been something meaningful in what I commented about, but I'll try to find what I referring to. ;)